# How can I drag an image to another position within a DIV (Similar to Facebook's album management)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

FOR EXAMPLE: i have 2 pics: pic 1, pic 2.
now i want to drag pic 2 in front of pic 1: pic 2, pic 1.
so how can i do it?
and if its possible please attachs some code.
thankful for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I guess sortable is best suitable for you. You can also review drag and drop functionality too.

Have a look on demo

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) framework.